# Python List comprehension of a file

Tags: python

While studying open cv with an online course I found this line of code

`classes = [r[r.find(' ') +1:] for r in all_rows]`

What does this `r[r.find(' ') +1:]` mean?
I'll include the entire code:

````
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('typewriter.jpg')


all_rows = open('synset_words.txt').read().strip().split('/n')


classes = [r[r.find(' ') +1:] for r in all_rows]

for(i,c) in enumerate(classes):
    if i==4:
        break
    print(i,c)



cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()```
````

Comment: Break it down. Do you know what `r[1:]`  means?

Answer (score 2):

`r.find(' ')` will find the index of the first `' '` character in the row `r`.

Adding one to it gives the index of the character after the first space.

`[:]` is slice notation. So you're taking the slice of everything in the row after the first space.

Comment: Might be helpful to say this is analigus to saying: `' '.join(r.split(' ')[1:])`. Great answer though!

Comment: @Jab You could add your own answer. It is less efficient though so not really a close analogy. `r.split(' ', 1)[1]` is more efficient and perhaps a closer analogy. Although, saying that, the behaviour would then be different if there were no spaces. Perhaps a regular expression is simplest.